# alist error when value created using (concat string1 string2)

Tags: backquote

I'm really confused with what's happening here.

In my config for backups I've the line `(setq backup-directory-alist '(("" . "~/.emacs.d/backup/per-save")))` and I've a defined a variable in my `init.el` like so:

```
(defvar user-home-directory (concat (getenv "HOME") "/")) 
(setq user-emacs-directory (concat user-home-directory ".emacs.d/"))
```

I tried to redefine `backup-directory-alist` like so:

`(setq backup-directory-alist '(("" . ((concat user-emacs-directory "backup/per-save/")))))`

But I'm getting the `wrong type argument stringp` everytime I try to save the file. What's going on! What am I doing wrong with *alist* value data.

Comment: You are trying to execute code inside a quoted expression, but the quoted expression is not interpreted as code. You could fix it by changing `'` to `\`` and using `,` in front of `(concat ...)`.

Comment: Ah that was an easy fix. My problem was, I did not know what to google search for.