# My Org mode capture code returns "Invalid file location: nil"

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, backquote

I use the following code for the org mode capture functionality, but it returns the error "Invalid file location: nil". What is wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
(setq org-capture-templates '(              
     (
    "t"                                                                                                  
    "todo"                                                                     
    entry                                                                                                
    (file (format "C:/Users/%s/Dropbox/.orgzly/capture2022.org" user-login-name))                   
    "* TODO %^{Todo}  \nSCHEDULED: %t\n:PROPERTIES:\n  :Created: %U\n  :NOBLOCKING: t\n  :ORDERED: t\n:END:\n:LOGBOOK:\n\n:END:\n\nFrom: %a\n\nNote: %?\n"  
    :prepend t                                                                                          
    :empty-lines 1
    )
))
```

Comment: Search for `backquote`. You are quoting the list *including* the call to `format`. You want to backquote it and precede the `format` call with a comma in order to allow evaluation:  ` `((... (file ,(format "/path/%s" user-login-name))...))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Comment: Hi NickD. I do not understand your answer above. I am only a part time emacs user with limited understanding of the coding. The code I use did work 2 years or so ago, so I have no clue why it doesnt work any more.

Comment: I added a (community wiki) answer. Hope it helps but keep asking if it's still not clear. The reason that it worked before and does not work now is a change that was made to Org mode back in version 9.1: see [etc/ORG-NEWS](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/etc/ORG-NEWS#n2378) or thereabouts (search for `org-capture-templates` if the link sends you to the wrong line).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patient answer below, I will study it thorourgly.

Comment: And your solution worked :) thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Making this a community answer: feel free to add more examples]

This is a FAQ as you will see if you search for `backquote`. The trouble with the general problem however is that it is a chameleon and tends to blend if you are not familiar with it, but it eventually starts jumping out at you.

The basic problem is that when you quote a list, *nothing* inside is evaluated. So if you do

```lisp
(setq mylist '("foo" (format "%s" "bar")))
```

the result is a list of two elements: the first element is a string but the second element is a *list*. The value is `("foo" (format "%s" "bar"))`. You might have expected it to be a list of two strings: `("foo" "bar")` but it is not. The quoting inhibits the evaluation of everything inside. That does not matter if the quoted list consists of constants which are self-evaluating, but it matters when what you think is a function call (e.g. `(format "%s" "bar")`) is not evaluated because of the quoting. I hope you can see what is happening in your case.

The solution is to make sure that the `format` call is evaluated. You do that by using [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) which allows you to *selectively* evaluate *parts* of a list while keeping *most* of it quoted. In the above example, you write:

```el
(setq mylist `("foo" ,(format "%s" "bar")))
```

Note the backquote (instead of a quote `'`) in front. That says  "quote everything except whatever follows a comma" [1]. Each expression following a comma is evaluated and its value *replaces* the expression in the result. So the value of the above is `("foo" "bar")`.

Note that you can have more than one expression evaluated by adding a comma before each one:

```el
(setq mylist `("foo" ,(format "%s" "bar") (format "%s" "baz" ,(format "%s" "hunoz")))
```

The value of `mylist` will be `("foo" "bar" (format "%s "baz" "hunoz")` since the first and third `format` calls are evaluated because they are preceded by commas, but the second `format` call is not evaluated because it is *not* preceded by a comma. That's what I meant by "selective evaluation" above.

You should try evaluating these expressions in your `*scratch*` buffer to see the difference. You should also do the same with your setting of `org-capture-templates` to see what is happening.

I hope you can see what you need to do in your case to do the evaluation. You just change the `'` quote to a backquote and add a comma before the `(format ...)` call (as I mentioned in my comment). Understanding what that does however will allow you to fix such problems in the future: it is well worth the effort.

[1] There is actually another wrinkle with `backquote` that I'm not covering here. See the link for the additional details.

---

Here's a partial list of questions whose answer is essentially the same as the answer above. The first one is often used as *the* paradigmatic example when asking to close such questions as duplicates. Note the variety of the questions: that's why I called it a "chameleon" before.

- [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)
- [How to use a variable for an output :file path for call-process](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71942/how-to-use-a-variable-for-an-output-file-path-for-call-process)
- [function accepts string literal, but not the result of expression](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71284/function-accepts-string-literal-but-not-the-result-of-expression)
- [Why is :box on set-face-attribute not getting the current value from (face-background)?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71157/why-is-box-on-set-face-attribute-not-getting-the-current-value-from-face-backg)
- [Key binding to `C-<` and `C->` not working when creating minor mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70714/key-binding-to-c-and-c-not-working-when-creating-minor-mode)
- [Function argument does not seem to be visible inside of function](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69608/function-argument-does-not-seem-to-be-visible-inside-of-function)
- [Passing string as arg to apply function](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/66621/passing-string-as-arg-to-apply-function)
- [string-join list with function as list member](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/62829/string-join-list-with-function-as-list-member)
- [Concat in Org Easy Templates](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44044/concat-in-org-easy-templates)
- [cons a symbol with a variable and return as a symbol](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37998/cons-a-symbol-with-a-variable-and-return-as-a-symbol)
- [What is missing to show the desktop-dirname in the frame title?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33708/what-is-missing-to-show-the-desktop-dirname-in-the-frame-title)
- [elisp - construct a quasi-alist from variable](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32099/elisp-construct-a-quasi-alist-from-variable)
- [Problems with setting the default font](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29603/problems-with-setting-the-default-font)
- [alist error when value created using (concat string1 string2)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29406/alist-error-when-value-created-using-concat-string1-string2)
- [How to use ,var-name (defvar) syntax in org-publish-project-alist? Init file is in form of org-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29351/how-to-use-var-name-defvar-syntax-in-org-publish-project-alist-init-file-is)
- [Can I eval a value in quote?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24298/can-i-eval-a-value-in-quote)