# Evaluate elements in an alist?

Tags: alists

I would like to evaluate an element in an alist, like dynamically generating an alist key for the current year:

```
((format-time-string "%Y") . ?y) => ("2022" . ?y)
```

(In my case the goal is to dynamically create a org tag for the current year in `org-tag-alist`, but this question is more general about alists.)

Even after reading manual entries for [alists](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html) and [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html) (which all alist construction examples I've found use), I am stumped how to achieve this elegantly.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Weird, not only did that question not show up in web searches, it did not show up in the suggested posts while creating this question.

Comment: Marked as duplicate. Hopefully this Q&A will show up in search results when the other does not, filling the gap and saving others time, which was my goal in posting this.

Comment: Although the *answer* is common, the *questions* that have this common answer are all over the place, which makes it hard to search for duplicates (or to provide automated suggestions). See [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72289/14825) for a partial list of questions whose answer is exactly the same: use `backquote`.

Answer (score 0):

[Backquotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) allow selective element evaluation:

```
`(,(format-time-string "%Y") . ?y)
```

The `,` indicates an element to be evaluated, so `,(format-time-string "%Y")` will evaluate to the current year (e.g., `"2022"`) while `?y` will remain unevaluted.

---

Example for `org-tag-alist` to create a tag for the current year, mapped to the `y` key:

```
(setq org-tag-alist `((,(format-time-string "%Y") . ?y)))
```

---

Using backquotes you can even splice lists into alists using `,@` notation, see  [doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) for details.

I have used elisp for years and never encountered backquotes! Hoping this will help someone find it when web searching. Credit to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19775433/376497) I stumbled upon while searching for a related issue.