# How to programmatically set the same flag for multiple transient-values?

Tags: magit, string, association-lists, alists, transients

How can I programmatically set the same argument (e.g., `--gpg-sign=abc123`) for multiple `transient-values`? If I try the following, it seems that the value of `adamliter/my-gpg-key-sign-git-arg` does not get expanded.

```el
(setq adamliter/my-gpg-key "abc123")
(setq adamliter/my-gpg-key-sign-git-arg (format "--gpg-sign=%s" adamliter/my-gpg-key))
(setq transient-values
      '(
        (magit-commit adamliter/my-gpg-key-sign-git-arg)
        (magit-fetch "--prune")
        (magit-merge adamliter/my-gpg-key-sign-git-arg)
        (magit-rebase "--autostash" adamliter/my-gpg-key-sign-git-arg)
        (magit-revert "--edit" adamliter/my-gpg-key-sign-git-arg)
        )
      )
```

After evaluating this, the value of `transient-values` is:

```el
((magit-commit adamliter/my-gpg-key-sign-git-arg)
 (magit-fetch "--prune")
 (magit-merge adamliter/my-gpg-key-sign-git-arg)
 (magit-rebase "--autostash" adamliter/my-gpg-key-sign-git-arg)
 (magit-revert "--edit" adamliter/my-gpg-key-sign-git-arg))
```

But I would expect it to be:

```el
((magit-commit "--gpg-sign=abc123")
 (magit-fetch "--prune")
 (magit-merge "--gpg-sign=abc123")
 (magit-rebase "--autostash" "--gpg-sign=abc123")
 (magit-revert "--edit" "--gpg-sign=abc123"))
```

Thanks in advance for the help. I'm not too familiar with Emacs Lisp, so assume I'm just making a simple mistake here.

Comment: Does this post (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7481/253) answer your question?

Comment: This is a dup: see the top answer to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/72261/my-org-mode-capture-code-returns-invalid-file-location-nil/72289#72289.  Long story short: look up `backquote`.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Yes, thank you. Sorry I didn't find that question when looking. Happy to close it as a dupe of [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list). Will just say as someone not that familiar with `elisp`, it wasn't obvious to me which part needed the backtick. Took me a bit of experimenting to figure it out, but it needs to be `\`((magit-commit ,adamliter/my-gpg-key-sign-git-arg))`. Thank you!